# Navigating through nested maps in Java

Tags: java

I am looking for an elegant way to get and put values in nested, untyped maps in Java.

For instance assuming I have a map structure as follows:

```
  Map m = { 
      "a": {
         "aa" : {
                  "aaa": "hello",
                  "aab": "world"
              },
         "ab" : { ... }
         },
      "b": {
         ...
         }  
    }
```

In Groovy I can access these values as easy as:

```
m.a.aa.aab
```

and even set/put values as

```
m.a.aa.aab = "univers"
```

while in Java, I am forced to write something like this to get the value

```
((Map)((Map)m.get("a")).get("aa")).get("aab")
```

and to set the value I would need to write

```
((Map)((Map)m.get("a")).get("aa")).put("aab", "univers")
```

Are there better ways/libraries to do this? The only thing I can think of are to write some helper methods like

```
public static Object getValueForKeyPath(Map map, List<String> keys) {
    if (keys.size() == 1) {
      return map.get(keys.get(0));
    } else {
      return getValueForKeyPath((Map) map.get(keys.get(0)), keys.subList(1, keys.size()));
    }
  }

  public static void setValueForKeyPath(Map map, List<String> keys, Object value) {
    if (keys.size() == 1) {
      map.put(keys.get(0), value);
    } else {
      setValueForKeyPath((Map) map.get(keys.get(0)), keys.subList(1, keys.size()), value);
    }
  }
```

which then can be used like

```
getValueForKeyPath(m, asList("a","aa","aab")
```

or

```
setValueForKeyPath(m, asList("a","aa", "aab"), "univers")
```

Comment: Are you only interested in strings as keys and leaves?

Comment: @Caleth: strings as keys but potentially numerical values.

Comment: But there is some small set of potential leaf types? are you reading JSON/XML?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? `Map` itself is a raw type, in your case, the type should be `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>`, and then you don't have to do any explicit cast. You can just do `m.get("a").get("aa").put("aab", "univers");`

Comment: @Vincent Savard: I have to work with a untyped Map, not because of the Java version I am using but because of how my interface is specified.

Comment: @Caleth: Kind of. I am not reading the xml myself but the map is constructed from parsing xml in another component of the system.

Comment: Then it seems that the Adapter pattern is your best bet. Implement the interface by casting the raw `Map` to the correct type, then forwarding it to an adapter that doesn't use raw types. Just because your interface is crappy doesn't mean you have to write crappy code. (And this is assuming you can't change the interface, if you can, then you should just do it.)

Comment: I'd take an XMLObject, rather than a raw map, in that case. Or at least something structurally similar